# In theory, is find_end parallelizable?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, parallel-processing

I'm currently working on an [open-std proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3960.pdf) to bring parallel functionality to the project I am working on, but I've run into a road block with `find_end`.

Now `find_end` can be described as:

> An algorithm that searches for the last subsequence of elements [s_first, s_last) in the
>   range [first, last). The first version uses operator== to compare the
>   elements, the second version uses the given binary predicate p.

it's requirements are laid out by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end). Now I had no problem parallelizing `find`/`findif`/`findifnot` etc. These could easily be split up into separate partitions that were executed asynchronously and I had no trouble. The problem with `find_end` is that splitting the algorithm up into chunks is not a solution, because if we have say a vector:

`1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 8`

and we want to search for `1 2`.

Ok first off I seperate the vector into chunks asynchronously and just search for the range in each chunk right? Seemed easy enough to me, however what happens if for some reason there are only 3 available cores, so the vector is separated into 3 chunks:

`1 2 3`|`4 5 1`|`2 3 8`

Now I have a problem, the second `1 2` range is split into different partitions. This is going to lead to a lot of invalid results for someone has `x` amount of cores that end up splitting the search results into `y` different partitions. I was thinking I would do some sort of `search chunks -> merge y chunks into y/2 chunks -> search ->` in a recursive style search, but this just seem's so inefficient, the whole point of this algorithm is to **improve** efficiency. I might be overthinking this ordeal as well

**tl;dr**, is there a way to parallelize `find_end` in a way I am not thinking of?

Comment: Why doesn't that work? I get that 1 and 2 are not in the same partition, but I don't see a problem there. Isn't it OK to step out of the assigned range for that? You wouldn't be stealing something that an other thread is responsible for, because the thing you're really partitioning is starting points.

Comment: @harold because I would be searching for this range only on each partition. each partition is seperated, launched on a thread and the results of each partition are represented in a vector of futures that I can then use `.get()` with. I have no way of knowing if a subsequence is split up, and with that these partitions are not communicating with each other

Comment: I agree with harold. It doesn't matter how you partition your chunks. The partitioning only needs to apply to the start point of the test, not its end point. You can allow the end point to run into the following partition. If you physically split up your partitions, then you are going to have to copy the data for every cell. That alone would probably offset any benefits parallelization would get you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Let `N` be the size of the range you are looking for.

Once you've separated your vector in 3 chunks (3 separate worker threads) :

```
1 2 3|4 5 1|2 3 8
```

You can allow each thread to run across its right adjacent chunk (if any) for N-1 elements (since only read operations are involved on the sequence, this is perfectly fine and thread-safe).

**In this case : (N = 2)**

- Core 1 run on `1 2 3 4`
- Core 2 run on `4 5 1 2`
- Core 3 run on `2 3 8`

Comment: Maybe it is better to make second chunk overlap on (N-1)/2 on the left, and first chunk (N-1)/2 on the right. Otherwise last chunk will be significantly smaller for bigger N

Comment: thanks for the fast response, this is definitely a great solution. I would be worried about having an uneven distribution on the partitions however, it could potentially make cores finish early and waste calculation power. Though I doubt find_end would ever be used in such a way that make this problem evident, I think it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Some cores will finish early and waste calculation power.  Almost any parallel algorithm with have this problem.  That is one reason why having N cores is never N times faster.  But that doesn't mean it isn't worth doing.

Answer (score 2):

Since the point of `find_end` is to find the *last* occurrence of a needle in a haystack, parallelization by splitting the haystack into contiguous segments is often not going to produce any benefit because if the needle is actually in the last segment, the work done by all processors other than the one assigned to the last segment is wasted, and the time is precisely the same as it would have been with a single processor. In theory, the parallel evaluation allows you to cap the maximum search time, which is of benefit if (1) processors are not in competition for other tasks and (2) there are relatively few instances of the needle in the haystack.

In addition, you need to be able to coordinate process termination; each process can abandon the search when it finds a match or when its younger sibling has either found a match or abandoned the search. Once process 0 has found a match or run out of places to look for them, the lowest-index process with a match wins.

An alternative is to interleave the searches. If you have `k` processors, then processor 0 is given the sequences which end at `last-0`, `last-k`, `last-2k`..., processor 1 is given the sequences which end at `last-1`, `last-k-1`, `last-2k-1`... and in general processor `i` (`0 ≤ i < k`) works on `last-i`, `last-k-i`, `last-2k-i`...

Process coordination is slightly different from the first alternative. Again, each individual process can stop as soon as it finds a match. Also, any process can stop as soon as its current target is less than the latest match found by another process.

While that should result in reasonable parallelization of the search, it's not clear to me that it will be do better than a non-parallelized linear-time algorithm such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt or Boyer-Moore, either of which can be trivially modified to search right-to-left. These algorithms will be particularly useful in the not uncommon case where the needle is a compile-time constant, allowing for the possibility to precompute the necessary shift tables. The non-interleaved parallelization can benefit from KMP or BM, with the same caveat as above: it is likely that most of the participating process will prove to not have been useful.